# Objective-C: Perform segue from an external class - Warning: Attempt to present * on * whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, segue

as said in the title, I would like to perform a segue from another class (not extending UIViewController, but which manages the connection to the database).

Basically I get this error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <RootViewController: 0x15680b00> on <LoginViewController: 0x15594290> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

And the RootViewController never appears.
(My RootViewController is the destination ViewController and LoginViewController is the ViewController from which I call the login method.)

Here's my code:

```
+ (void) login :(NSString*) username :(NSString*) password {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"function": @"login",
                             @"username": username,
                             @"password": password
                             };
    [manager POST:serverURL parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
        NSLog(@"Login user %@", username);
        if (200 == [[response valueForKey:@"code"] integerValue]) {
            [DatabaseManager fetchUser:[[CacheHandler instance] currentUser]];

            // Perform segue to ActivitiesViewController
            UIStoryboard *msb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
            LoginViewController *lvc = [msb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
            [lvc performSegueWithIdentifier: @"segueActivities" sender:self];

            [[CacheHandler instance] setToken:[response valueForKey:@"token"]];
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [AlertHelper error:@"Failed to log in: wrong password!"];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

I don't get it because the LoginViewController must be loaded in the window hierarchy since I call the login method with an action on a button after a while.
Or maybe the LoginViewController I instantiated is not the one loaded on the screen?

Thanks!

Comment: No, I've just tried with an instance method, no change…
It's a class method on purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty clear that your `LoginViewController` is not in the view hierarchy (i.e., not on the screen) given that you instantiate it and immediately segue to it without adding its view as a subview anywhere. What you probably want to do is grab a reference to the visible view controller via the app delegate.

Comment: Thanks, I understand, although I have no clue how to do that.
The login method is in a class extending NSObject… how do I reach the app delegate?

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]

Comment: Although, that said, if you're calling this function from LoginViewController, you should probably just make your function instance-level instead of class-level (change the "+" to a "-") and then you can just use the self keyword.

Comment: I haven't been clear, actually LoginViewController calls login method that way:
[DatabaseManager login:[usernameField text] :[passwordField text]];
That's why I couldn't have only changed the method to instance method.

Comment: Understood. In order to prevent this kind of coupling (a DatabaseManager really shouldn't need to know about the login UI), you may want to look into posting some kind of "loginSucceeded" notification via the NSNotificationCenter. Here is a really good article on the topic http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look! This is my first iOS app, these kinds of hints are helping me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You create Login controller in memory but it's not a part of window. You have to wire it up somehow with storyboard flow, by modally presenting it using `presentViewController` Or creating segue that wires current controller  and Login controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows a class method, so it isn't associated with any instance of that class.

Then, in your login method you instantiate an instance of `LoginViewController`, but this instance isn't presented, you have just created it.  You then try and perform a segue on this new instance, resulting in the exception message, which is pretty clear, you are trying to perform a segue on a view controller that isn't in the view hierarchy